# Calculate square of 3dsolid

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to calculate the square surface of 3dsolids using the Viewer API?

Example of the drawing: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d66556x8lkyu29n/FF1.dwg

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in feature in the Forge Viewer API to do that, it is based on underlying THREE.js API, so you need to find how to do that from a THREE.Mesh: [Calculate superficial area and volume of mesh with Three.js (WebGL)](http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-uepuawvq-tr.html)

Comment: How can I access  underlying THREE.js  objects?